# rails tutorial chapter 10 sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org, sendgrid, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm newbie, and self-teaching myself via Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-email_in_production).

I've made it as far as Chapter 10 and have everything working in development but after adding Sendgrid my push to heroko it is rejected with the following:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `action' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fc6e0b67778>
```

I'm on Rails 4.2.0.  I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.  Here's my production configuration:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'salty-plateau-4554.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

And my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

Please send wisdom in bulk.

Comment: You seem to have `config.action.mailer`. Maybe not `mailer`, something else. A project-wide search for `config.action.` might yield something.

Comment: Agree to the above comment. Do a `grep -r "config.action." *` from your app folder to find the rogue config.

Comment: If you get desperate, I would also recommend contacting Michael Hartl himself.   I've gone through his tutorial before and he was responsive when I had issues.  You can use the contact info on the railstutorial website.

Comment: have you restart your rails server????

Comment: Did you set up the SendGrid app on heroku?

Comment: I set up SendGrid from the command line: "heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter" it seemed to have worked.

Comment: I'm using the Cloud9 development environment.  So I *think* I've restarted the rails server.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add sendgrid-ruby gem in your production gemfile and push on heroku.